# git how to push code to a submodule in github

Tags: git, github

I'm now working on a project which has a submodule in it from GitHub.

I get the code by directly `git clone`, I changed something in the submodule and try to push them into GitHub server.
But by doing that, the submodule in the GitHub becomes empty.

I search the internet and it seems I should first push the submodule, however, when I go into the submodule, and do `git status`, I realize Git doesn't recognize I'm in the submodule and all the status is still on the big project.

So what I want to know is: how to push the submodule to the GitHub  and fix this?
My GitHub account should have the permission of modifying both the big project and the submodule.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, clone your GitHub repo again, reset it to a state before your last problematic push (maybe `git reset --hard @~1` is enough, check with `git log`), and try to apply your modification again.

This time, add and commit and push from within the submodule folder first.
Then go to the parent repo (your GitHub repo you have cloned), add, commit and push.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, but when I go into submodule folder, I can't push them because git does not automatically change into the git for submodule, so I can't push or commit the submodule separately. I used git clone to clone the whole project, is it automatically clone the submodule repository or it only clone the files in?

Comment: @RushengZhang with a recent enough git, a git clone would checkout the submodule as well.

Comment: @RushengZhang But after a reset, you would need to do a `git submodule update --init`

Answer (score 1):

First check is there any submodules repo available in your .gitmodules folder 
It should show :

```
[submodule "sub repo name"]
    path = xx-name
    url = https://github.com/yoursubmodule path
```

If it is present then your git commands in your sub-module should work

Update:

**Cloning a Project with Submodules**

When you clone such a project, by default you get the directories that contain submodules, but none of the files within them yet.

You must run two commands: `git submodule init` to initialize your local configuration file, and `git submodule update` to fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject:

Or

There is another way to do this which is a little simpler, however. If you pass **--recursive** to the git clone command, it will automatically initialize and update each submodule in the repository.

```
$ git clone --recursive <url>
```

Comment: @RushengZhang Yeah Glad to you help. Welcome!